# What is this plant with waxy, variegated, 7" by 4" oval leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I bought this plant yesterday, but there was no identification tag. The leaves are large, thick, and waxy (succulent-like) and about 7 inches long by 4 inches wide. I don't think it is a [Peperomia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peperomia) or [Hoya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoya), which are the closest guesses I have been able to make. I hope to be able to get help identifying it so that I can take care of it properly.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This plant is Peperomia obtusifolia 'variegata' based on the thick stems and waxy leaves. More details are found [here](http://apps.rhs.org.uk/plantselector/plant?plantid=1409).

- it normally reaches a height of 10 to 50 cm
- prefers moist soil
- it grows well part shade
- normally trouble free but I have seen hard scale attack this plant if they are already present on other plants
- buds off old stems so can be cut back if it gets a bit leggy
- the flower is a curious stalk that is usually seen in mid summer.  It will drop pollen